# Check whether the element is present or not in an array

Tags: php

This is my array. I want to check whether 'NASHIK'  is present or not in this array. I have used `in_array` function but I did not get correct output. Help me to findout solution.

Thanks in advance.

```
Array
(
    [Neo] => 16686
    [new] => 16799
    [PUNE] => 17371
    [NASHIK] => 17373
)
```

Comment: [isset](http://php.net/isset)?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)? It searches a value but you want to search a key. You can try [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

Comment: Laravel is not involved in this question.

Comment: @JonStirling  Thanks...Isset working for me

Comment: @axiac, Thanks...Isset working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the key of the array, not the value. That's why in_array() is not the correct one.

You need [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) for that.